# White Screen on iOS app for certain domains. domain=NSURLErrorDomain

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I have been through many different posts on the issue and unable to find a resolution to my problem. I have created a webview iOS app that displays a certain domain hosted in AWS. I have tested this with a local ip and it worked fine, also tested with another website which worked but my domain is not loading. My only error in xcode is

```
0x112821620 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=14,946] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=1, isMainFrame=1, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=18,446,744,073,709,550,416, isMainFrame=1, willInternallyHandleFailure=0
```

The webview code is basic although I have tried many different solutions. I have used http and https, again the local server was http which worked great, just had to be on the local network.

I do not mind sharing my code as it is basic and non proprietary.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://app.saiko.cloud/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

I am just not sure what else to check to get it to load. The app does not seem to try and establish a connection to the domain tested with wireshark. I am assuming it is all http/https traffic and I do not need any other security exceptions on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was add this to the info.
`<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>`
I did not think that was the answer as it could connect to http on the local lan when using a private address, iOS must be able to make that distinction.